# Class 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean' not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I dont know why I am having the above error on this line of my code

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

this is the complete code

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:db/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260131/java-spring-hibernate-cannot-find-org-springframework-orm-hibernate3-localsess

Comment: is that a maven build project? this is a maven project

Comment: don't you know how to add a missing jar with maven?

Comment: are you using spring? some of the spring versions doesn't match with some of the hibernate versions. or check your dependencies, sometimes they are incompatible with main jars.

Comment: Okay. Good point. it is a spring project with maven build

Comment: we might need more information like your console log

Comment: I have no console logs for this error

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem long ago and this was my solution :

> Hibernate 4 support was added to Spring Framework in 3.1.
>
> Your pom.xml references Spring Framework 2.5.6 hence
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean does not
>   exist. You need to update your pom.xml to reference Spring Framework
>   3.1 or later.

ref : [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548499/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-orm-hibernate4-localsessio)